# Getting the path part of a URI

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I match the `/sk/en` and `/fg/tr` from these URLs?

```
http://example.com/sk/en
http://example.com/fg/tr
```

URLs can start with `http://`, `https://`, or `www.`, but don’t have to. There are always two letters after the first and second slash, and letters are alphabetic and can be called in anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need to use a Regular Expression for this.

```
var url = new URL("http://example.com/sk/en");
console.log(url.pathname); // logs /sk/en
```

This will work with http and https, but if you need to support URLs without a protocol (which are by the way, invalid urls) just prepend http to them.

Alternatively, if you need to support old browsers, you can always use the DOM less directly:

```
var a = document.createElement("a"); // create a link element
a.href = "http://example.com/sk/en";
console.log(a.pathname); // /sk/en
```

The [`URL` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) is rather new, so it requires IE10+ and a relatively new Chrome/Firefox to work.

The `createElement` approach will work on older versions of IE too, so if you need to support older browsers - prefer it.

---

You're mentioned in a comment you need the first two bits after the path, once we have the pathname, we can split it. Let's say we have our path variable we can use `indexOf` and compare it to 0

```
var path = "/ab/cd/ef/gh?foo=bar";
console.log(path.indexOf("/ab/cd") === 0); // true, since /ab/cd is exists in the path
                                           // and its start position is 0
console.log(path.indexOf("/cd/ef")); // 3 and not 0, since it's not at the first position
console.log(path.indexOf("/en/us")); // -1, not found at all.
```

Comment: The URL class is useful, never knew about it before!

Comment: Wow! I never knew about either of these things. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: but it matches path of any length. I need only /ab/cd. Basically I need to know whether a url contains that bit after the main part.

Comment: @KananFarzali then you can `.split` it and check, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @KananFarzali I've verified all the snippets I included in my answers all compile and run. How about you check for yourself?

Answer (score -1):

See **Edit** below for updated answer.

But as Ben said, no need for RegEx. But his method doesn't access the current browser window url. In order to get the current window/tab path after the hostname, use `window.location.pathname'.

So:

```
alert(window.location.pathname);
```

for this page will alert:

`/questions/23916101/url-regex-matching-javascript`

**EDIT**
To find within a full pathname, here's the regex you'd need in your examples, but use my above window.location.pathname to get the browsers current url instead of the created object for the example if that's what you're after.

```
var url1 = new URL("http://example.com/sk/en/abc/def");
var url2 = new URL("http://example.com/fg/tr/abc/def");
console.log(url1.pathname.match(/\/sk\/en/));
console.log(url2.pathname.match(/\/fg\/tr/));
```

This will match and log the result if that expression is contained anywhere in the pathname as you'd mentioned. If you're wanting to verify that it's at the beginning of the pathname, simply modify the regexs with ^ (example `/^\/sk\/en/`)

Comment: Nobody said it was the current URL.

Comment: Correct, but no one said it wasn't either. I've updated my answer. I've also added the regex as an answer as the OP originally wanted. Benjamin's answer is spot on too, just a different way of skinning the cat.

Comment: `/\/sk\/en/` is already a regular expression, by the way. `new RegExp(/\/sk\/en/)` doesn’t do anything more.

Comment: `new RegExp(/\/sk\/en/)` still works. Code was tested in Chrome before posting as is. Although you are correct as this could be simplified, updating the answer to remove the redundant `new RegExp`'s.