# Javascript Domain / Subdomain Extract Path

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following domains and I'd like to use javascript to return a certain 'prettified' label from each.

```
http://mydomain.com/page1/ --> "Page 1"
http://mydomain.com/page-with-hypens/ --> "Page With Hypens"
http://test.mydomain.com/  --> "Test"
http://blog.mydomain.com/ --> "Blog"
http://blog.mydomain.com/2014/01/17/i-am-a-blog-article --> "I am a Blog Article"
```

At first I was just using something like `.replace()` but then realized that wasn't going to cut it.

Comment: I'm not entirely understanding what you're trying to do. So, for the pages that come directly from your website, you want to put spaces between characters? And for regular URLs that are subdomains, you want to return the name of the subdomain?

Comment: Something to get you started: [`https?:\/\/(?:(\w+)\.)?mydomain\.com(?:\/([^\/]+))*\/?$`](http://regex101.com/r/oM3kV1)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916101/getting-the-path-part-of-a-uri/23916124#23916124. You can use the `hostname` property to get the subdomain (split on `.`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the current URL via window.location. Given your requirements above, you could create a pretty title using the following:

```
// Use window.location for pieces...
var domain = "jsbin.com",
    host = window.location.host.split('.'),
    path = window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/,'').split('/'),
    subdomain = host.length === 3 ? host[0] : undefined,
    post = path.length ? path[path.length - 1] : undefined;

var title = subdomain || (post && post.replace('-',' ')) || 'Not Available';
console.log("title: " + title);
```

The 'Not Available' could be replaced with whatever default title you want when the page is exactly (http://mydomain.com) with no subdomain and no path.